# Editing the model in a ListView

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm currently making a website for my parent's bakery. And I want to make a custom admin page for them so they can update their products with ease.

All I have so far is a ListView that displays all the products. 
[image]

This is my model:

```
class menulist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=10, default=100.00)
    category_choices = (
        ('breads', 'Breads'),
        ('cakes', 'Cakes'),
        ('hotfood', 'Hot Food'),
        ('porkrolls', 'Pork Rolls'),
        ('drinks', 'Drinks'),
        ('MISC', 'Misc'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=category_choices, default='MISC',)
    dateadded = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    dateupdated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', default='products/blank.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The View:

```
class ProductAdminView(ListView):
    template_name = 'menulistapp/product_admin.html'
    queryset = menulist.objects.all()
```

The template:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}        
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

          <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 15%"scope="col"></th>
                    <th style="width: 55%" scope="col">Product Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle"><img src="{{ obj.img.url }}" class="img-fluid"></td>
                    <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.name }}</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.get_category_display }}</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">${{ obj.price }}</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.dateadded }}</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.dateupdated }}</td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>

      </div>
  </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

How do I separate the items into their own category tables?

And how do I make it so that each cell is editable with their own CharField, and there's a "SAVE" button at the bottom of each table?

EG:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the concept of forms to attain that

For more information, go through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Comment: Thanks. But I read the whole section and the closest they came to explaining how to edit the fields is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method. But the method only applies to single objects, and I can't figure out how to make it work on a listview.

Comment: @PaulZet , Documentation talks about [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) too. You can edit multiple objects using the concept of formset